# OpenTK/OpenGL local axis rotation

Tags: opengl, rotation, opentk

Here is a scenario:

Object is described by:

- Position
- Scale
- Rotation

First I apply model view (camera) from OpenGL, then Translation and Rotation using following matrix:

```
    private Matrix4d AnglesToMatrix(Vector3d angles)
    {
        Vector3d left = Vector3d.UnitX;
        Vector3d up = Vector3d.UnitY;
        Vector3d forward = Vector3d.UnitZ;

        AnglesToAxes(angles, ref left, ref up, ref forward);

        return new Matrix4d(
            new Vector4d(left.X, up.X, forward.X, 0),
            new Vector4d(left.Y, up.Y, forward.Y, 0),
            new Vector4d(left.Z, up.Z, forward.Z, 0),
            new Vector4d(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    private void AnglesToAxes(Vector3d angles, ref Vector3d left, ref Vector3d up, ref Vector3d forward)
    {
        const double DEG2RAD = 0.0174532925;
        double sx, sy, sz, cx, cy, cz, theta;

        // rotation angle about X-axis (pitch)
        theta = angles.X * DEG2RAD;
        sx = Math.Sin(theta);
        cx = Math.Cos(theta);

        // rotation angle about Y-axis (yaw)
        theta = angles.Y * DEG2RAD;
        sy = Math.Sin(theta);
        cy = Math.Cos(theta);

        // rotation angle about Z-axis (roll)
        theta = angles.Z * DEG2RAD;
        sz = Math.Sin(theta);
        cz = Math.Cos(theta);

        // determine left axis
        left.X = cy * cz;
        left.Y = sx * sy * cz + cx * sz;
        left.Z = -cx * sy * cz + sx * sz;

        // determine up axis
        up.X = -cy * sz;
        up.Y = -sx * sy * sz + cx * cz;
        up.Z = cx * sy * sz + sx * cz;

        // determine forward axis
        forward.X = sy;
        forward.Y = -sx * cy;
        forward.Z = cx * cy;
    }
```

at, the end I apply scale. All looks great except rotation, which is based on global axis.

How to rotate objects using local axis?

To make question precise. When I rotate object by 45 degree on Y axis then X and Z axis are rotated with it and then applying another rotation use new axis.

To avoid punishment in form of minuses... I read all subjects related to rotation in 3D space, non of them gave me solution. Above code is a result of applying various attempts, but it produces result same as:

```
        GL.Rotate(Rotation.X, Vector3d.UnitX);
        GL.Rotate(Rotation.Y, Vector3d.UnitY);
        GL.Rotate(Rotation.Z, Vector3d.UnitZ);
```

**EDIT:**
As it turned out, our designer had bad expectations about rotations of objects in 3D, but still the problem exist. As for language used, we write this in C#, but if you point me a solution in C or C++ I will handle it :D

We currently use (order can be configured):

```
GL.Rotate(Rotation.X, Vector3d.UnitX);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Y, Vector3d.UnitY);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Z, Vector3d.UnitZ);
```

But this rotates objects around world axis. What we want is to use local object axis like this assuming we have X-Y-Z axis rotation:

```
GL.Rotate(Rotation.X, Vector3d.UnitX);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Y, newYaxis);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Z, newZaxis);
```

or assuming we have Y-X-Z axis rotation

```
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Y, Vector3d.UnitY);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.X, newXaxis);
GL.Rotate(Rotation.Z, newZaxis);
```

Most efficient way would be to pre calculate rotation matrix, but still I'm wondering how to determine new axis after rotation. (it seams that I have to revisit trigonometry book). If someone have solution which would calculate rotation matrix really fast I would be grateful. For now I will try to use trigonometry calculations in each pass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with opentk, but for C style opengl this is the difference between pre-multiplication and post-multiplication. Pre-multiplication occurs in world-coordinate space, post-multiplication occurs in local-coordinate space. See http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm section 9.070.

If you can get a handle to the actual matrices to perform the matrix multiplication, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you say exactly what kind of situation you're envisioning here?

I don't believe your request makes any sense. With any rotation, you can either apply it before another operation (global axis), or after another operation (local axis). Therefore if you want to apply three rotations, one axis rotation must be first, another axis rotation must come second, and another axis must come third.

You're saying you want to apply three rotations, but you want each rotation to occur before the other two. They can't all be first.

If you put more description (images preferred) of what kind of rotation you're trying to achieve maybe we can clear up this misunderstanding, but what you're currently asking does not make sense to me in physical reality.

Comment: Rotations must occur in specific order, but after rotating around one axis I have to calculate new axis for next rotation.